# Getting error while commending WORKDIR in Dockerfile, what is the reason?

Tags: docker

I am trying to implement `java` in `docker` using  `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:7
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac welcome.java
CMD [ "java" , "welcome" ]
```

When I commended the `WORKDIR` and prepared a build command, I got following error

> **javac: file not found: welcome.java Usage: javac   use -help for a list of possible options**

What is the reason for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WORKDIR` is the default directory your container will use when you log in (and also the base dir for any subsequent relevent commands in a Dockerfile, see [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) for more info).

If you comment it out, the container will use the `WORKDIR` defined in the base image. Since `openjdk:7` does not define one (you can check that with `docker inspect openjdk:7 | jq '.[0].WorkingDir'`), the default `WORKDIR` is `/`

In your Dockerfile, you copy the content of your current dev directory to `/usr/src/myapp` inside the container. Your command to compile your file uses a relative path.

Since you dropped the `WORKDIR` definition, `javac` is now looking for a file `welcome.java` in the current dir `/` and that file does not exist.

So either keep the `WORKDIR` definition, or use absolute path in your `RUN` **and** `CMD` definitions for your classpath:

```
RUN javac /usr/src/myapp/welcome.java
CMD ["java", "-classpath", "/usr/src/myapp", "welcome"]
```